# Correlation between p-value and linear regression slope in general linear model

Tags: r, lm

I input a counts table (read counts mapping to 600 sequences in a reference fasta) into a package that runs a linear regression using a general linear model lm() in R, and outputs a trend line slope and p-value for each of the 600 sequences. I made a volcano plot of my results (b.value = regression slope) and found an unexpected correlation between the regression slope and the p-value. Can anyone explain why this might be the case? going through the code for the package, but I want to know if this could actually be an issue with the input data rather than the model? [image]

The code for running the linear regression on the counts table "dat$count" with the response variable given by "condition" is given by:

```
do.lm <- function(dat) {
  count <- dat$count
  col_data <- dat$col_data
  tidy.count <- count %>% 
    cbind(name = rownames(count)) %>%
    gather(sample, count, -name) %>% 
      left_join(col_data %>% rownames_to_column("sample"), by = "sample")    
  # TIP: values in a column must be atomic, can't have a vector
  res <- tidy.count %>% group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(count = list(count), 
              condition = list(condition)) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate( lm = list(summary(lm(unlist(condition)~unlist(count)))),
            baseMean = mean(unlist(count))) %>%
    mutate( p.value = tryCatch({lm[[1]]$coefficients[2,4]}, error = function(e) NA),
            b.value = tryCatch({lm[[1]]$coefficients[2,3]}, error = function(e) NA)) %>%
    select(name, baseMean, b.value, p.value)
  res$padj <- p.adjust(res$p.value, method="fdr")
  res
}
```

Comment: See [this response](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/111776/) to a similar question at Bioconductor support. It suggests that the input data does have an issue.